# Addition of 2 signed numbers saved in 32 bit registers.. what's the carry flag and the result?

Tags: cpu-registers, addition, complement

Lets say we have the following 2's complement values saved in 32 bit registers (A and B): 7FFFFFF0 and 0000002F, and we wanted to add them both then add binary 1 and save them in a different register(C)... what is the result? and what will the carry flag be?

I know that the result will be 80000020 but this is negative. Is this what's going to be saved in the register C?

Comment: The hexadecimal is a red herring, by the way. No computer I'm aware of uses hex internally for machine code. It's all binary, all the time.

Comment: @NathanTuggy What has internal representation got to do with it? Hex values can be used to unambiguously represent 32 bits (as can decimal or any other base)

Comment: @MadPhysicist: Indeed. But my point is, nobody cares (least of all the computer) if you're adding signed *hexadecimal* numbers. Just flat doesn't make any difference. (That's why I said "red herring".)

Comment: @Josh, It will not be negative. Twos complement represents negative numbers by subtracting them from zero in a limited space of digits (pretend that there is a `1` in the 33rd bit of the zero). So adding positive numbers can give you a negative number.

Comment: @NathanTuggy. I see your point and agree now that your edit has made it clear. Hex is totally irrelevant here.

Comment: @MadPhysicist okay but Is the value "80000020" going to be stored in that register?

Comment: Yes. Addition is done bitwise, any overflow over 32 bits is just discarded.